Are Sobolev norms all the same?
I am interested in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, where $p\in[1,+\infty], \ \Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set. This is defined as the set of functions $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ such that they admit the weak partial derivatives $\partial_i f$, and they again belong to $L^p(\Omega)$, for $1\le i \le n$. However, I realized that different books come with different definitions, and I don't understand if they are all equivalent, or there are subtleties to pay attention to. For example take [1] (Evans), [2] (Brezis) and [3] (Adams) as a reference.
Evans takes:

$$ \|f\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} = \Big( \int |f|^p + |\nabla f|^p dx \Big)^\frac{1}{p} \ \text{ if } p<\infty $$
$$ \|f\|_{W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)} = \text{supess}_{x\in\Omega} |f(x)| + |\nabla f(x)| $$

This already raises one question on itself: wouldn't it be more consistent, to follow the lines of definition 1, to define
$ \|f\|_{W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)} = \text{max} \{ \|f\|_\infty, \|\nabla f\|_\infty \} $ ?
Brezis takes:

$$ \|f\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} = \|f\|_p + \sum_{i=1}^n \|\partial_i f\|_p \ \text{ for } p\in[1,\infty] $$
which claims to be equivalent to
$$ \|f\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} = \Big( \|f\|^p_p + \sum_{i=1}^n \|\partial_i f\|^p_p \Big)^\frac{1}{p} \ \text{ for } p\in[1,\infty] $$

Finally, Adams takes:

$$ \text{same as Brezis, for} \ p<\infty  $$
$$ \|f\|_{W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)} = \text{max} \{ \|f\|_\infty, \|\partial_1 f\|_\infty, \dots, \|\partial_n f\|_\infty \} $$
where again, with definition 1. I would've expected more $ \|f\|_\infty + \|\partial_1 f\|_\infty + \dots + \|\partial_n f\|_\infty $

Now, my question is: are these all equivalent definitions? To be honest, I don't even know what I mean by equivalent. For one: are they equivalent in the sense that they generate the same topology? Or something more, or something less?
Moreover: isn't 2. from Evans fundamentally different from, say, 2. from Adams? What I mean by this is: 2. from Evans is a sup that needs to compromise between two terms of a sum; whereas 2. from Adams treats each derivativative independently.

[1] Evans, Lawrence Craig; Gariepy, Ronald F., Measure theory and fine properties of functions, Textbooks in Mathematics. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4822-4238-6/hbk). 309 p. (2015). ZBL1310.28001.
[2] Brezis, Haim, Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations, Universitext. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-70913-0/pbk; 978-0-387-70914-7/ebook). xiii, 599 p. (2011). ZBL1220.46002.
[3] Adams, Robert A., Sobolev spaces, (1975).

Two norms $|\cdot|$, $|\cdot|$ iff there exist constants $c$, $C$ such that $c |x| < |x| < C|x|$ for all $x$. Sobolev norms are usually the textbook examples for this property because some forms are easier to motivate but some are easier to use in proofs

@whpowell96 thank you for your comment. Does that mean that all three "1" are equivalent, as well as all three "2"? I am mostly doubtful about Evans' "2"...

All are equivalent and showing so is a typical exercise. There are other definitions that are harder to work with but finding appropriate constants $c$ and $C$ for these is not difficult.

@whpowell96 I haven't tried yet, but their equivalence wouldn't surprise me, except for Evans' 2. That is because I would expect the equivalence to come more or less directly from the equivalence of the standard $p$-norms in $\mathbb{R} ^n$, but that one in particular has a quite different look...

$\max{|f|{\infty},||\nabla f||{\infty}} \leq ||f|+|\nabla f||{\infty} \leq 2 \max{|f|{\infty},||\nabla f||_{\infty}}$. You can make similar bounds for sums of $\infty$-norms if you prefer that.

Ah, sure, of course! Sorry, I didn't see that. Thank you!
